# How do I Separate an Array Value from input to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm getting this value from the page source (after the page finished loading), the data is coming from a back-end process that populates a hidden text input on the page. I wish to separate this data and then display it in HTML format.

This is the code from 'View Page Source'

```
<input name="hiddenUserStats" type="hidden" id="hiddenUserStats" value="
99.0~35.0~8.0~.0~1.0~6.0~3.0~.0~1.0~3.8~1.8~1.0~.0~16.0" />
```

On the value, I'm assuming that each `.0~` separates the true value that I wish to separate and display. Anyone know what would be the best step to separate and display such data? Do I start with separating them in variables?

Comment: `document.getElementById('hiddenUserStats').value.split('~');`

Comment: Here's more info about `split`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: Thank you, I wouldn't have thought about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `split()` function to separate your stats values.

```js
var value = document.getElementById('hiddenUserStats').getAttribute('value');

var stats = value.split('~');


for (i = 0; i < stats.length; i++) 
{
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerText = stats[i];
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<body>
<input name="hiddenUserStats" type="hidden" id="hiddenUserStats" value="
99.0~35.0~8.0~.0~1.0~6.0~3.0~.0~1.0~3.8~1.8~1.0~.0~16.0" />
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, I made some tweaking to your code but in the end it pointed me to what I needed. I would still be scratching my head it if wasn't for your example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using native array methods;

```
    document.getElementById('hiddenUserStats')
    .getAttribute('value')
    .split('~')
    .map(function(val, i) {
        return '<div>' +  i + ': '+ val + '</div>';
    })
    .forEach(function(el) {
        document.body.innerHTML += el;
    });
```